# How to clear form after submission in rails using (stimulus) hotwire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo, hotwire

I have a form which creates a new post, and a stimulus controller that clears the input fields after submission. However, it does this before the input values reach my rails controller.

This is my `form_controller.js`

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  clear() {
    this.element.reset()
  }
}
```

my form:

```html
<turbo-frame id='<%= id %>'>
  <%= form_with model: post, data: { controller: :form } do |f| %>
    Title: <%= f.text_field :title %>
    Body: <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.submit data: {action: 'form#clear'} %>
<% end %>
</turbo-frame>
```

Everything works great, except that an empty post gets created (I
have no validations) because my input fields are wiped clean by the Js before
they reach my Rails controller.

I did look around and found this post but don't really know what to do.
[How to clear a text area after an "ajax" form request with ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915288/how-to-clear-a-text-area-after-an-ajax-form-request-with-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event is being executed on submit button click instead try running it on form submit. Didn't test the code but you might want to do something like this:

**Try 1:**

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

  connect() {
    this.element.addEventListener("submit", clear);
  }

  clear() {
    this.element.reset()
  }
}
```

And remove the action from submit button:

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

Or you can try this (running the action on turbo submit):

**Try 2:**

```
<turbo-frame id='<%= id %>'>
  <%= form_with model: post, data: { controller: :form, action: "turbo:submit-end->form#clear" } do |f| %>
    Title: <%= f.text_field :title %>
    Body: <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</turbo-frame>
```

Comment: yup the second snippet works. I also found a discussion thread on the hotwire forum that addresses the same issue.

https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/resetting-form-after-turbo-streams-submission/3615

Comment: I have the same use-case as OP and the second solution worked perfectly. Thank you.